# Как найти сумму последовательности целых чисел через рекурсию. Например от 1 до 5

Tags: javascript

Например: от 1 до 5 // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15

Comment: спросили и тут же сами ответили. и зачем вопрос было писать? пожалуйста, попробуйте его переформулировать, нажав [edit], чтобы было понятно, что именно вас интересует.

Comment: Разность между членами последовательности всегда равна единице?

Comment: Интервал равно единице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```js
/**
 * Функция находит сумму последовательности чисел используя рекурсию
 * @param begin начало
 * @param end конец
 */
const sequenceSum = (begin, end) => {
        
    if(begin == 0 && end == 0){
        return 0;
    }else if(begin == end){
        return begin;
    }else if(begin > end){
        return NaN;
    }    
    return begin + sequenceSum(begin + 1, end);            
};

console.log('Сумма чисел: ', sequenceSum(1,5)); // 15
```

Comment: Работает спасибо!

Comment: Зачем нужно отдельно `begin == 0 && end == 0 -> 0`, если есть `begin == end -> begin`?

Answer (score 1):

Существует особый вид рекурсии - хвостовая рекурсия. Такая функция в некоторых случаях эффективнее обычной рекурсивной функции.

```
const sumOfSequences = (begin, end) => {
  const iter = (counter, acc) => {
    if (counter === end) {
      return acc + counter;
    }
    return iter(counter + 1, acc += counter);
  };

  return iter(begin, 0);
};

console.log(sumOfSequences(1, 10200));
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсия

```
function sum(num) {
    if (num == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return (num + sum(num - 1));
    }
}

console.log(sum(5)); // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const sequenceSum = (begin, end) => {
  if (begin > end) {
    return NaN;
  } else if (begin === end) {
    return begin;
  } else {
    return begin + sequenceSum(begin + 1, end) /*Функция будет вызвана столько раз, пока begin === end */
  }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]